# Why Decklink Convert 1080p30 to 1080i60?

Tags: c++, directshow

Output of my DirectShow graph is 1080 FPS 30. When i send this input to Decklink Renderer. Decklink Device detect 1080i60 input. Why this happened?
How could force Decklink to use Progressive mode instead of Interlaced Mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeckLink DirectShow filters, Decklink Video Capture and Decklink Video Render, support less modes than hardware and underlying SDK. Also, they implement support for interlaced video combining fields as if video was progressive. This results in having the same media type for 1080i60 and 1080p30 modes, and filters interpret the media type as interlaced.

Use DeckLink SDK to output 1080p30, with or without building your renderer filter on top of it.

Also, Blackmagic Design hosts their own forum for software development questions: https://forum.blackmagicdesign.com/viewforum.php?f=12